# What exactly is transmission time?

Tags: computer-networks

Seems very trivial but I'm confused which one of these correctly define transmission time.

- Time taken by a message to reach receiver.
- Time taken to push message on the link by the sender.

Which one is correct one?

Answer (score 2):

- Time taken by a message to reach receiver : **Propagation delay or time**
- Time taken to push message on the link by the sender : **Transmission time**

Transmission time is the time from the first bit until the last bit of a message has left the transmitting node. Or, in simple word it's the amount of time required for the **router to push out** the packet.

```
Packet transmission time = Packet size / Bit rate
```

**Reference :**

- [in2p3.fr/actions/formation/InfoTempsReel/IN2P3-Ch1-datatran-tr.pdf](http://www.in2p3.fr/actions/formation/InfoTempsReel/IN2P3-Ch1-datatran-tr.pdf)

Comment: Or Propagation time is time to reach destination by $1$st bit?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. yep, in other words you can say it's taken by one bit to travel from one node to the other (it's proportional to the length of the wire, mainly).